# Validating if a string represents an integer or a float in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I am doing a college work that requires inputs of integers, I now need to make an algorithm that validates if the user actually wrote an integer so that the program doesn't error-out. My solution to this problem was to instead of using syscall 5 to input an integer, to input a string and then check if there are alphanumericals in it, if not check if there is a '.' to check if its a float, and if none of the above happend, come to the conclusion that it is an integer.

```
inputstr: .asciiz "Number "
buffer: .space 20
printinteger: .asciiz "Its an integer"
printfloat: .asciiz "Its a float"
notanumber: .asciiz "It's not a number"
zero: .byte '0'
nine: .byte '9'
dot: .byte '.'
.text
.globl main
main:
lb $t1, zero
lb $t2, nine
lb $t3, dot
#Read the string
la $a0, inputstr
li $v0, 4
syscall
la $a0, buffer
li $a1, 20
li $v0, 8
syscall

#Begining of validation

la $a0, buffer

loop:
lb $t0, 0($a0)
beq $a0, $zero, integer
blt $t0, $t1, checkdot
bgt $t0, $t2, error
addi $a0, $a0, 1
b loop

checkdot:
blt $t0, $t3, error
bgt, $t0, $t3, error
la $a0, printfloat
li $v0, 4
syscall
b end


error:
la $a0, notanumber
li $v0, 4
syscall
b end


integer:
la $a0, printinteger
li $v0, 4
syscall


end: 
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

At the moment the float validation is working but if the number is an integer it gives the same error as if it contained alphanumericals.

I have already done some debugging and realized that when the input is an integer, it still goes to the checkdot label and goes to the error label through this line: `blt $t0, $t3, error`

Comment: Are you trying to allow hex for integers but only decimal for floats?  Like 1234abc567 is a valid integer?  Your current code treats the first byte `> '9'` as an error, and ASCII `'A'` and `'a'` are greater than `'9'`.  Also, your function doesn't check the characters after the `.` to make sure they're all decimal digits, and there aren't multiple dots.  Also, checking for alphanumeric (instead of just digits or hex digits) wouldn't reject letters like `'h` and higher that aren't valid hex digit.  Base 37 can use all of `'0'..'9'` and `'a'..'z'` as digits, in which case sure just alphanumeric.

Comment: MARS/QtSpim syscall #8 appends a newline character to the end of the user input string, as if the carriage return they type counts, and yes, whether you want it or not.  So, you're probably running into that.  You can (1) remove the newline with a separate pass/loop as some programs like to do, or (2) simply stop with success if you reach a newline character, as there won't be anything useful after it except that nul-byte.  (The only time the newline will be absent is if the user fills the buffer full.  The nul-byte is always provided.)

Comment: However, let's note that the reason the float check works is because you stop looking for illegal characters once you hit the decimal point, which is how you avoid the newline issue there.  In other words, `25.Z` will pass your float test.

Comment: Let's also note that when most people think of debugging, they think of single step — and that is an excellent tool.  However, I suspect that you failed to inspect your data, both as stands in memory right after a syscall #8, and, also during single step debugging, as the characters are pulled into CPU registers from the string.  Add getting to know your data, and how to read it to your debugging skills!  Had you looked at the data you would have seen the newline character.  Have to admit though that looking at strings in data printed by MARS as little endian hex 32-bit numbers is awkward.

Comment: @ErikEidt Dude, you literally gave me the exact answear I needed by telling me about the new line, now I just check if the character is a new line and thats it, Its working like a charm. 
Thank you so much for the dedication and time spent on answearing my question, have a good one.